# SpatialRepository in Embedded Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

Can someone answer this question. Is it possible to have the spatial repository in a spring boot app in embedded mode?

```
  @Bean
       public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
          return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("neo4j.db");
   }
```

by just adding the

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
  <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

to your classpath?

I keep getting the error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No index provider 'spatial' found. Maybe the intended provider (or one more of its dependencies) aren't on the classpath or it failed to load.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getIndexProvider(IndexManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.findIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:209)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(IndexManagerImpl.java:314)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:302)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.createIndex(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.createIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:108)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityIndexCreator$2.doWithPersistentProperty(EntityIndexCreator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityIndexCreator$2.doWithPersistentProperty(EntityIndexCreator.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityIndexCreator.ensureEntityIndexes(EntityIndexCreator.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.updateStoredEntityType(Neo4jMappingContext.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.initialize(Neo4jMappingContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 62 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this repository in your maven pom

```
            <repository>
                        <id>neo4j-contrib-releases</id>
                        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/releases</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                        <id>neo4j-contrib-snapshots</id>
                        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/snapshots</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
```

with the dependency

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13-neo4j-2.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have spring data neo4j + spring boot.

You can find the code I wrote here: https://github.com/inserpio/neo4art
And a short post describing how I did it: https://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/neo4art-moves-to-cloud-foundry-at-springone-2gx-2014/

Hope it can help!

Cheers,
Lorenzo

Comment: Thanks but I see you are using the server rest implementation, I needed one that works with embedded.

Comment: I use both ones, but in the following class I configure the connection to neo4j in a embedded fashion: https://github.com/inserpio/neo4art/blob/master/src/main/java/it/inserpio/neo4art/boot/MyNeo4jConfiguration.java
How can I help you?

Comment: It appeared to be a problem with the neo4j spatial repository. After some research I found the right one. The http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_spatial doesn't work.